# caret renaming coefficient names in model

Tags: r, r-caret

Why does `caret` renaming the coefficient name?

The [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)

data(BostonHousing)

model <- train(medv ~ .,
               data = BostonHousing,
               method = "lm")

> model$coefnames
 [1] "crim"    "zn"      "indus"   "chas1"   "nox"     "rm"      "age"     "dis"     "rad"     "tax"    
[11] "ptratio" "b"       "lstat"

> colnames(BostonHousing)
 [1] "crim"    "zn"      "indus"   "chas"    "nox"     "rm"      "age"     "dis"     "rad"     "tax"    
[11] "ptratio" "b"       "lstat"   "medv"
```

And, the result contains `chas1` which doesn't exist in the data.

Am I missing something from `caret`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not missing something in caret. Just using `lm` will give you the same result.

```
lm(medv ~., data = BostonHousing)
Call:
lm(formula = medv ~ ., data = BostonHousing)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         crim           zn        indus        chas1          nox           rm          age          dis          rad  
  3.646e+01   -1.080e-01    4.642e-02    2.056e-02    2.687e+00   -1.777e+01    3.810e+00    6.922e-04   -1.476e+00    3.060e-01  
        tax      ptratio            b        lstat  
 -1.233e-02   -9.527e-01    9.312e-03   -5.248e-01
```

It has to do with the fact that chas is a factor containing the values 0 and 1. The coefficient chas1 is based on this factor. If chas1 == 1 the coefficient is used otherwise it is not. IF chas had 3 levels (0, 1, 2) you would see chas1 and chas2 appearing as coefficients.

Comment: Thanks! I was working with `caret` and `lm` only with numerical data and this was an unexpected thing.